# Customize the section title with Latin Modern

Tags: fonts, sectioning, titlesec

I have created a thesis using `mathptmx` font. Now I would like to customize only the section title using Latin Modern Sans Bold.

I used `titlesec` with

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\fontfamily{lmr}\sffamily\bfseries\Large}
{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

I would like to know if this is right because I'm not convinced.

Comment: You should say `\fontfamily{lmss}\bfseries\Large`

Comment: Thanks egreg. I didn't know the existence of that font family

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the default sans serif family in your document, which is done by saying

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
```

in the preamble. Thus each call of `\sffamily` in the document will choose the Latin Modern Sans font corresponding to the other specifications. For setting the section title you'll simply say

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\sffamily\bfseries\Large}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
```

This is based on the obvious assumption that you should not have two different sans serif fonts in a document.